# add error bar to a plot matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

suppose that I have this plot.

```
x = 0:pi/10:2*pi;
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = sin(x-0.25);
y3 = sin(x-0.5);

figure
plot(x,y1,'g+',x,y2,'bo',x,y3,'c*')
```

Now I would like to add vertical error bars (standard errors) to each of the points of the 3 waves.

Supposing that the values of the 3 standard errors are in the vectors

```
e1
e2
e3
```

how can I plot them on top of the markers representing the waves (I would like also to maintain the color)

Comment: I tried with the function error bar, but it connects the points...

Comment: ok Linestyle 'none' solves the problems.!